# Suddenly get catkin_make error

Tags: catkin-make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am new in ROS, I am using ros kinetic and ubuntu 16.04, I am working with kinect v2, I was trying to install ORK

then I got error when I did catkin_make, now I already delete what I installed but I am still getting same error with catkin_make,

any one can help me please ?

> This code block was moved to the following github gist:
> https://gist.github.com/answers-se-migration-openrobotics/8974154a048cd00c49f555bd73ac49b2

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/262086/suddenly-get-catkin_make-error/) by [Abdu](https://answers.ros.org/users/30451/abdu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2017-05-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you haven't already: please try to remove your `devel` and `build` directories. It looks like something was left behind that is now interfering with the build (I see mention of `ros_comm` in there, which is now not in the list of packages considered for the build).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-05-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0